# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta de la imagen guardada en nodejs/express para poder guardarla en mi base de datos?

Tags: nodejs, angular

Tengo un formulario con varios campos. Cuando hago el `submit`, tengo una función `createBook(event: Event)` que hace dos cosas: por un lado guarda la imagen en una **carpeta uploads** en `Nodejs`, y por el otro, guarda los datos del formulario en la base de datos `Postgresql`. Pero obviamente el **campo url_Image** de mi base de datos queda vacío.
¿Cómo hago para obtener la ruta de la imagen guardada en `Nodejs` y así poder guardarla en la base de datos?

Muestro foto de la carpeta donde se guarda la imagen en Nodejs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá del lado servidor, el archivo `server.ts` para guardar la imagen

```js
import express from 'express'
var multer  = require('multer')
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors'); 
const path = require('path');

import booksRoutes from './routes/books.routes'

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(booksRoutes);

// ******************* PARA HACER UPLOAD DE IMAGE ******************* //
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
    //carpeta donde va a guardar las imgs
    callBack(null, 'uploads') 
  },
  filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
    // guarda la img con el nombre
    callBack(null, file.originalname);
  }    
});

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  dest: 'uploads/',
  //dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/uploads'),
  limits: {fileSize: 2000000}, //max permitido de image, 2 mega byte de peso
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;   // expresion regular
    // mimetype checkea si el archivo es valido ej img/extension del archivo
    const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
    // con path.extname checkea si la img tiene la extension .jpeg o .jpg o .gif o .png
   const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname));
   if (mimetype && extname) {
     return cb(null, true);
   }
   else {
     cb("Error: el archivo debe ser una imagen valida");
   }
 }
}).single('file');

var upload = multer({ storage: storage});

app.post('/file', upload, (req, res, next) => {
  // aunque el req.file lo marque en rojo, dejalo asi, funciona bien
  const file = req.file;
  console.log(file);
  if(!file){
    console.log('No se subió ninguna imagen');
  }
  res.send(file);
});
// ******************* FIN UPLOAD DE IMAGE ******************* //

app.listen(4000);
console.log('Server on Port', 4000);
```

Acá también lado servidor Nodejs, `books.routes.ts`

```js
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = Router();
import { createBook } from '../controllers/books.controller'

router.post('/books', createBook); // crear libro

export default router;
```

Acá también lado servidor Nodejs `books.controller.ts` donde recibe los datos del formulario desde `Angular` y los guarda en la base de datos.

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { QueryResult } from 'pg'
import { pool } from '../database'

export const createBook = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
  // recibo los datos (de un form, insomnia rest, etc..)
  const { name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state} = (req.body);
  console.log(name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state);
  // el id_book en la db es autonumerico no hace falta
  let book_year = parseInt(year);
  let id_aut = parseInt(id_author);
  let id_cat = parseInt(id_category);
  let id_edi = parseInt(id_editorial);
  let cantidad = parseInt(quantity);
  let precio = parseInt(price); 
  // let idBook = parseInt(id_book);
  // insert en PostgreSQL
  const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('INSERT INTO books (name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)', [name, book_year, id_aut, id_cat, id_edi, description, cantidad, precio, url_image, state]);
  return res.json({
    message: 'El libro ah sido creado exitosamente!',
    body: {
      books: {
        name
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Acá del lado **Frontend**, el componente `books.component.ts`

```js
book = {} as Book;
image;
// para hacer un preview de la img seleccionada
imgPreview: string | ArrayBuffer;

buildForm() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.year)]],
    author: ['', [Validators.required]],
    category: ['', [Validators.required]],
    editorial: ['', [Validators.required]],
    description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2500)]],
    quantity: ['', [Validators.required]],
    price: [0, [Validators.required]],
    image: [''],
    state: [true]
  });
}
      
createBook(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.form.valid) {
    if (confirm('¿Esta seguro/a que desea agregar el producto?')) {
      // obtengo todos los valores del formulario
      this.book = this.form.value;
      this.book.id_author = parseInt(this.selectedIdAut);
      this.book.id_editorial = parseInt(this.selectedIdEdi);
      this.book.id_category = parseInt(this.selectedIdCat);
      this.book.url_image = '';
      // SUBO IMAGEN ////
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.image);
      // subo la imagen a nodejs
      this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:4000/file', formData).subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res),
        (err) => console.log('El servidor no guardó la img, no reconoce el formato: ' + err)
      );
      ////// fin upload image //////////
      // guardo los datos en la base de datos
      this.bookService.createBook(this.book)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
      // vuelvo a a traer los libros
      this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName();
      this.resetForm();
      this.book = {} as Book;
      // this.toastr.success('Operación exitosa', 'Producto agregado!');
    }
  }
}
selectImage(event){
  if (event.target.files.length > 0){
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.image = file;
    // preview de la img
    const reader = new FileReader();
    // leo el archivo seleccionado
    reader.onload = e => this.imgPreview = reader.result;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Acá `books.component.html` con el formulario (muestro solo dos campos del formulario para que el Código no sea tan largo)

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="createBook($event)">
       
  <div class="form-group col-md-9 mb-3">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" 
      [(ngModel)]="book.name" placeholder="Nombre de libro"
      (blur)="book.name = cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(book.name)">
    <div *ngIf="form.get('name').errors && form.get('name').dirty">
      <p class="text-center mt-1" *ngIf="form.get('name').hasError('required')">Este campo es obligatorio!</p>
      <p class="text-center mt-1" *ngIf="form.get('name').hasError('maxlength')">El nombre es muy largo!</p>                             
    </div>                  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Imagen</label>                       
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image"
      formControlName="image" multiple (change)="selectImage($event)">
    <div *ngIf="imgPreview != null" class="text-center my-2">
      <img [src]="imgPreview" class="img-fluid">
    </div>                           
  </div>   
            
  <div class="text-center">
    <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Guardar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-white" (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
  </div>               
</form>
```

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado larga y la respuesta demasiado corta: La ruta donde se almacenan las imágenes siempre será la ruta raíz de tu proyecto + 'uploads', que es el nombre que pasas como carpeta de destino a `multer`. Saludos

Comment: gracias por responder, pero estoy confundido, en la base de datos deberia figurar por ejemplo C:/nombreDeMiProyecto/server/uploads/nombreDeImagen ?

Comment: Se almacenará así, si usas la ruta absoluta, pero mi recomendación es que guardes sólo la ruta relativa. En tu caso particular: `'/uploads'`, así, si cambias el proyecto de carpeta, no será problema ubicar la imagen, ya que un simple `path.join(__dirname, imagePath);` te dará la ruta de la imagen, siendo `imagePath` el valor que está almacenado en tu base de datos, y siendo [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) el valor de la ruta raíz de tu proyecto. Saludos

Comment: Gracias mauricio, pero esa ruta la debo indicar  en la funcion createBook() en Angular, es decir this.book.url_image = '/uploads/' + this.image; ?

Comment: Pues eso dependerá de lo que pretendes lograr con tu aplicación. Mi opinión es que el frontend no tiene porqué decidir u opinar sobre dónde se almacenará una imagen. Tu `backend` es el único encargado de decidir dónde se almacenan las imagenes o archivos que envías desde el `frontend`. Incluso, deberías guardar la imagen usando un nombre aleatorio, para evitar problemas con nombres repetidos, aunque se trate de diferentes archivos, y en la BD, almacenas el nombre original que tenía la imagen al momento de recibirla. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, entiendo lo que dices, pero sigo estancado porque no se como hacer que desde el backend, guarde la ruta de la imagen en la base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115660/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-claudio).